# Timeout exception with JsonpRequestBuilder accessing google web page

Tags: java, gwt, jsonp, javascript-objects

so I'm currently trying to use the JsonpRequestBuilder API to try to access a remote file however I'm just testing with the google webpage link and I'm getting a Timeout exception. Not too sure what I'm missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

`package com.webapp.client;`

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.webapp.client.ExcelFileJavascriptObject;
import com.google.gwt.jsonp.client.JsonpRequestBuilder;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public class DataHttpRequest {

```
private final String url2 = "http://www.google.ca";

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("DataRequest.java");

public void retrieveFile() {
    JsonpRequestBuilder builder = new JsonpRequestBuilder();

    builder.requestObject(url2,
            new AsyncCallback<ExcelFileJavascriptObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    logger.severe(caught.getMessage());
                    logger.severe(caught.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ExcelFileJavascriptObject result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Window.alert(result.toString());
                }
            });
}

public void onModuleLoad() {
    retrieveFile();
}
```

}

`package com.webapp.client;`

import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;

public class ExcelFileJavascriptObject extends JavaScriptObject{
    protected ExcelFileJavascriptObject(){

```
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking the '[Some Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)' ajax restriction. You only could download that file using Ajax if your GWT app were deployed at 'http://www.google.ca' what I suppose it is not, isn't it?

The only way to get info from a different domain is: using '[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)' like you are trying to use, or '[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)', in both cases the other domain should have an agreement with your application, in order to set the appropriate headers in case of you wanted to use CORS, or in order to wrap the response with a callback if you wanted JSONP, what it is not happening with the url you are trying to request.

If you want to explore both methods, this [Ajax page](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax#getJSONP%28%29) I wrote for the gwtquery project could be useful.

Comment: I did use a JSONP request builder for that reason? Am i using it wrong?

Comment: As I say, when you use JSONP, the other part must offer that service as a jsonp service. If you request the `http://www.google.ca?callback=whatever` it returns a normal html text. Jsonp enabled sites return a javascript text surrounded with a callback like this `https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/user_id/posts/post_id?callback=whatever`.

Comment: Oh then what if what I really want to access is just a ftp link which an Excel file, am I using the wrong class, I don't think I can use your custom classes as this is for a school course.

Comment: you cannot get FTP info from javascript, it only speaks HTTP.

Comment: How should I proceed then?

Comment: create a link `ftp://user:password@ftpserver/file` in your page so as the user can download the file to his/her computer, or create a `Frame` with that url so as the user is automatically asked to download the file.

Comment: It is a fast solution but has a big security issue : you have the password in clear in the url! this could be copy pasted by the user...

You can also create a servlet that will read and forward the file content (or cache-forward). The servlet will have a regual url with your domain name: behind the scene, the servlet will connect to the other server to get the data

Answer (score 0):

JSONP loads a JavaScript (using a `<script>` element to *bypass* SOP) with the convention that the script simply calls a function whose name is passed as argument in the script URL's query-string and which takes a single argument.

That means you cannot use it to *load* an Excel file.

In [this post on the GWT forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/RSEBXXUdCYU/E4TQhe6Li58J), you're saying you want to “download an Excel file from a different domain onto the GWT servers and then parse it later on”.
If you want to load things from server to server, don't go through the client: use a `URLConnection`, or Apache HttpClient, JAX-RS 2 Client API (using Resteasy or Jersey as implementation), OkHttp, etc.